# How to rotate line chart in SSRS 2008?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting, reporting-services

I need to rotate line chart control of SSRS shown below. Whatever I do I cant find any way to rotate it. So I decided to ask it to stackoverflow.

Any help or idea will be appreciated.

> **Normal:**

```
Y axes

|

|

----X axes
```

> **It should be :**

```
          X axes

          |

          |

Y axes ----
```

Comment: just change the respective coordinates x from (+ to -), and swap the x coordinates with y

Comment: It is not easy like your advice. SSRS tool is really restricted fro these operations...

Comment: i dont have the knowledge of SSRS.. best of my knowledge that may work... but sorry if that is not implementing

Comment: yes unfortunately it is not implementing. I have never seen the buggy and restricted tools  like SSRS :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved  my problem with some tricks.

If you faced with such kind of problem in SSRS with line chart:

Change type of chart from line to bar chart.

1. Enter Properties Window of series properties.
2. Set fill property "No Color"( Unfortunately you have to do this for
   each ChartData...).
3. Set Legend property( Color and shape...) ( Unfortunately you have to
   do this for each ChartData...).
4. Set PointWidth Property 0 for
   each series.

To find PointWidth property Firstly,click each series and show Properties Window of Visual Studio. It is under Custom Attributes.